# How to mach a string when not followed by another with sed

Tags: sed

Does anybody knows how to match with sed each 'foo' instance excepted when it is following by 'bar' in the following string?

> 'foo       boo      foo
>      foo       bar foo
>       foo
>           foo'

Desired result (matched instances in bold)

> '**MaTcHeD**       boo
>        **MaTcHeD**    foo
>         bar **MaTcHeD**    
>   **MaTcHeD**          **MaTcHeD**'

After a big amount of tests, I found:

```
sed -e "s/foo\( *\)bar/FOO\1BAR/g" -e "s/foo/MaTcHeD/g" -e "s/FOO\( *\)BAR/foo\1bar/g"
```

It consists in first matching 'foo bar' instances and replacing them with some temporary string (here 'FOO BAR'), then in matching the resting 'foo' instances before replacing "back" the 'foo bar' ones to their original version... (I hope I am clear...)

But anyway this is not clean at all. I would be surprised there is not a more straight way to do it, even if I have not been able to find it out so far.

Any hint would be appreciated. :-)

Thank you very much,

Comment: is the string with regular separator? e.g. space or tab? I mean, the `foo bar` part, has fixed spaces?

Comment: The separators consist in a variable amount of spaces (but spaces only).

Sed is not a must as long as I can replace the matched occurrences with something else but without modifying the space character distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have to stick to `sed`, your idea is ok. However if the original string has `FOO BAR`, your solution fails. You have to always choose a right temp string. It makes your script insecure.

you could improve it by not choosing regular String as the temp string, but those **invisible** strings.

For example, this line works:

```
sed -r 's/foo( *)bar/\x94\1\x98/g; s/foo/Matched/g;s/\x94( *)\x98/foo\1bar/g' file
```

Comment: Year! Thank you very much :) You picked up the exact problem of my solution.

Comment: Well, I don't know why you chose precisely x94 and x98, but it seems that one can use all characters from x80 to xFF, the ones belonging to the extended ASCII table. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @taalf no particular reason, because I pressed 4 and 8. after 9. :)